# encoding 100,000s variables in each time step of RNN tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I’m looking for some pointers on efficiency. I have potentially 100,000s of binary variables that i wish to encode in each time step of an RNN for binary classification of the entire sequence, but I am torn between trying to encode every feature in each step (will be very, very sparse), or just use for a better word a “dodge” effect where if 3 out of the 100,000’s of variables = 1 (the vast majority at each time step will be 0) then these 3 occurrences just take up a separate time step each. For example if i have:

```
ID   Event_type (100,000’s of different types)
—    —————————-
1.   A
1.   BX
1.   ZZA
2.   YZAE
3.   C
3.   FXN
```

where for each ID, these events all appear in time = 1, I either

1. Create a very sparse representation at each time step that includes many 0’s to indicate all the events *not* experienced at this time step
2. Or do something like this:

> ```
> [
>  [[1,[“A”],
>      [2,[“YZA”],
>      [3,[“C”]] ,
>
>  [[1,[“BX”],
>      [2,[0],
>      [3,[“FXN”]],
>
>  [[1,[“ZZA”],
>      [2,[0],
>      [3,[0]]
> ]
> ```

i.e. pad out the sequences and effectively turn this 1 time step into 3 time steps (ID A has the largest number, 3 events in this particular time step).

Has anyone had to deal with many features per time step before, where they are always sparsely populated?

Comment: IMHO this should be asked on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/